# Difficulty with a simple regex for .obj files

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse lines of the form:

```
command arg1[ arg2, ... argn]
```

such as:

```
usemtl weasels
```

or

```
f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9
```

Here is my regex:

```
^(\\w+)(( \\S+)+)$
```

When I parse the line "usemtl weasels", I get the following capture groups:

```
Match 0: 'usemtl weasels'
Match 1: 'usemtl'
Match 2: ' weasels'
```

Why the space before the second match group? It doesn't show up in Rubular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping in java regex is a little strange. Group 0 gives you the complete match of your regex - this is the same in all regex implementations I know. But group *n* (for *n* >= 1) will give you the last match of the *n* th declared group, not the *n* th match found.

Your second match gives you ' weasels' with a leading blank, because your pattern contains that blank. You declared your 2nd group `(( \\S+)+)` and this group gives you the second match.

If you apply your pattern to the string `a b c d`, your group 0 will be `a b c d`, group 1 will be `a`, group 2 will be `b c d` and group 3 will be `d`, because this is the last match of your 3rd declared (inner) group `( \\S+)`.

Comment: Hm. From my perspective, *"the last match of the n'th declared group"* is the only logical thing. What regex engine gives you the n'th match found? This makes no sense at all.

Comment: OK, perhaps it was only me who was confused about this, because I expected to be able to reference all matches even if a group matched multiple times.

Comment: Following your logic, would that mean that in `(a)*(b)` the `b` would be represented by different numbers depending on how often `a` matched? That's just not right. ;-) The .NET framework [supports `CaptureCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection(v=VS.90\).aspx) which lets you do this kind of thing. However, that's a rather unusual feature with regex engines.